# Implement iterator in Doubly-Linked List

Tags: java, list, iterator, doubly-linked-list

How do I implement a class that provides an iterator for iterating over a Doubly-LinkedList? This should be implemented as a private inner class within the Doubly-LinkedList class.

```
private class Iterator<T> iterator(){ 
for(i = 0; list.size() > 20; i++){
System.out.println("Using the iterator approach (numbers > 20) your list is: ")
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Yes I have tried many things. I tried to implement as a class but it doesn't know the list I am trying to reference when I try to use it. The list is in the Driver class that has all of the output information. I have tried this:

Comment: private class Iterator<T> iterator(){

Comment: Please add your code in your question

Comment: for(i > 20; list.size(); i++){ System.out.println("Using the iterator approach (numbers > 20) your list is: ")

Comment: See this link. Sometimes it may help you. https://gist.github.com/yetanotherchris/4960171

Comment: That didn't help. The tough part for me is understanding how the iterator can be a private inner class inside of a class that does not even have public static void main(String[] args) in it.

Comment: Same as for a Singly-linked list

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your Doubly-LinkedList class. But it may be something like this.

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>() {

        Node<T> node = head;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return node != null;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            T value = node.value;
            node = node.next;
            return value;
        }
    };
}
```